# Как Opencart 2 определяет товары-новинки? Как, например, увеличить их количество?

Tags: opencart

Добрый день. Как Opencart 2 определяет товары-новинки? Как, например, увеличить их количество? Поискав по интернету, стало понятно, что Opencart 2 формирует новинки по дате добавления. Но где эта настройка? Это 3 дня, 5 дней, 10? И как этим управлять? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите про стандартный модуль Latest, то найдите в его контроллере `catalog\controller\module\latest.php` следующие строки:

```
$filter_data = array(
            'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit']
        );

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

Это вызов метода модели `getProducts()`. В $results вернётся массив продуктов, сотрированых по `date_added DESC`, в количестве `$setting['limit']`, которое вы указываете в настройках модуля, в админке. А днями вы никак не управляете.Для этого необходимо немного изменить логику:

```
//catalog\controller\module\latest.php
$filter_data = array(
            'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit'],
            // добавим в фильтр значение дней, за которые хотим получить новинки
            'days'  => '10',
        );

//catalog\model\catalog\product.php
//ищите такой блок кода:
 $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
        WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'
        AND p.status <> 0 AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
//и после него вставляете проверку последних  дней.
    if(isset($data['days'])){
        $sql .= " AND p.date_added > (NOW() - INTERVAL ". (int)$data['days'] ." DAY)";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Количество меняется в админке, в настройках модуля поменяйте лимит.

Дату правьте в mysql, посредством phpmyadmin или выгружайте через админку - экспорт\импорт (ветка oc_product), вас интересуют **date_added** и **date_modified**, редактируя любым привычным редактором, добьётесь нужной сортировки, далее сохраняете и импортируйте назад.