# отображение модуля "Новинки" в меню и на главной одновременно

Tags: php, меню, opencart3.x

Доброе утро всем. как сделать чтобы модуль "Новинки" был ссылкой в меню? чтобы одновременно отображались первые 8 товаров на главной(limit 8), но так же в меню был раздел и при переходе отображало все товары из новинок с убранным лимитом. подскажите,как реализовать,спасибо!

Comment: Модуль новинки не получится посадить на роут. У него своя функция - быть блоком для вставки в определённом месте какого-то лейаута. Смотрите реализацию special (не того, что в controller/extension/module а того, что в controller/product). На его основе можно сделать свой роут на товары-новинки. Или покупайте/качайте расширение, нагуглить готовое решение не сложно.

Comment: как пример https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=64661

Comment: тут за лимит и более тонкую настройку (oc2.x) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697711/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-opencart-2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE